# Display the address of the web view in the text view

Tags: url, webview, textview, toolbar

I want to create an application that shows my website page in the webview and everything works correctly.
But my problem is that I want the new site address to be displayed in the TextView when I click on the url in the webview.
For example, when I click on the Google site, my textview will show https://google.com to the user so that the user can understand what site he is in. Thank you.

I want to display the address of the new site in the form of a TextView in the toolbar when my site enters another site so that the user can be informed of the site's address.